# Lazy Loading UIScrollView or UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

I am looking for a bit of advice. I am building a photo editing app that needs to display thumbnails horizontally across the screen (20+). Each thumbnail is created by passing a small image through `GPUImage` and then displaying it on screen using threads.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

                UIImage *imageWithEffect = [self editImage:[obj objectAtIndex:0] ImageToEdit:thumbnailImage];

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                         [imageViewWithEffect setImage:imageWithEffect];
                         [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

                    });

            });
```

Currently I am using a `UIScrollView` to display the images but I am finding that it is taking a while to process all the images. What I would like to do is "lazy load" the images when the user slides the `UIImageView` into view. The problem is I am unsure how to go about finding what images are currently in view.

Some people have mentioned that it may be easier to use `UITableView`s instead. Could anyone offer some advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on HOW you want to display your data (i.e. picture + title + details about the pic OR just in simple, plain imageView) it is indeed easier to go for UITableView or UICollectionView given the fact that this lazy loading is the default, built-in and hardly avoidable behavior of those 2 classes.

Both of them are scrollable and displays cells (UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell) that can be designed via the StoryBoard (i.e.: add an imageView there, a label underneath...) and use the delegation pattern to lazily ask the controller what to display when a cell is about to arrive on screen.

Let's assume you wish to use a collectionView (yo could then display several imageView in a grid-like layout) but a tableView would work 99% the same way. 
First thing you'd have to do is to add collectionView to your StoryBoard and add inside the collectionView a UICollectionViewCell and customize it with your own design (i.e. add an imageView inside). Your collectionView can contain multiple cell design (just an imageView for normal images, an imageView with a "new" ribbon for newly added images, an imageView with a "last edited by " textField for edited images) although you should give (still in the storyBoard) a unique identifier for each of your design, an within each design set a tag value for each of your cell's UI components.

Once your layout is completed, declare your scene controller as the datasource for your collectionView and conform the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol by implementing the methods

`- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;`

`- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

The first one must return the total number of image you want to display (so that the underlying scroll view could scale it's content size), and the second one is for you to return the cell to display at the given indexPath which is basically an wrapper class that contains a item index and a section index.
The second method is called lazily when a cell is about to appear on screen, so in this method you can retrieve your thumbnail image according to the indexPath.item value (being the index of the image to be displayed), get a cell with a StoryBoard define design by sending the `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`to the collectionView. Fetch your cell's design element by their tag value by sending the `-(UIVIew *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag` message to the cell returned by the previous method and then set their text / image property to be what you want to show to the user.

This was a rather théorical approach of your answer, I'll be happy to help you more technically shall it prove to be necessary.

Cheers,

Comment: Great answer. +1 for the collection view approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Tableview** which is more flexible for this. You can easily load and made selection easily. And also I suggest **UICollectionView** for this. It's also more useful for this.

**Problems with scrollview:** Before scrolling, you need to add and load all images in one time which make your app slow down. `Frame calculation` is also little bit complex based on your requirement.